# Calculus Bonus Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

solve algebraically

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x+x^2}$$

without using L'hopital's rule

This is a bonus question for my Math Intensive Major Cal 1 class, I would like to know how to solve it since it stumped me on the test, and after many hours of working at this problem it has stumped me again and again

Comment: You could use $a^{12}-b^{12}=(a-b)(a^{11}+\ldots+b^{11})$.

Comment: Taylor series/generalised binomial theorem will do nicely.

Comment: we can't use Derivitives (haven't covered it in class yet, I'm going to hate it for the week when I can't use power rule)but I will bring Up julian's solution at study group tonight

Comment: @IvanLoh If the OP can't use l'Hopital, I doubt he/she can use Taylor.

Comment: Hmm I guess so. Your approach should be the best way to go about it then.

Comment: thank you for the answers!  we solved it another longer way that I'll try to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use the formula
$$
a-b=\frac{a^{12}-b^{12}}{a^{11}+a^{10}b+\ldots+ab^{10}+b^{11}}
$$
with 
$$
a=\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad b=\sqrt[4]{1-2x}.
$$

This gives
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}=\frac{(1+x^2)^4-(1-2x)^3}{a^{11}+a^{10}b+\ldots+ab^{10}+b^{11}}=\frac{6x-8x^2+\ldots}{a^{11}+a^{10}b+\ldots+ab^{10}+b^{11}}
$$
$$
\frac{2x(3-4x+\ldots)}{a^{11}+a^{10}b+\ldots+ab^{10}+b^{11}}.
$$
So 
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}}{x+x^2}=\frac{2(3-4x+\ldots)}{(1+x)(a^{11}+a^{10}b+\ldots+ab^{10}+b^{11})}.
$$
Now note that both $a$ and $b$ tend to $1$, so your limit is
$$
\frac{2\cdot 3}{12}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: It seems much more convenient to split this into two pieces as in Babak's answer so that you only need third-order and fourth-order identities.

Comment: @ErickWong Baback uses Taylor, and the OP does not even know what a derivative is. Of course I would do it with Taylor otherwise! And I disagree, doing both third and fourth order identites separately, or directly writing the 12 order one, does not make a big difference when you use dots. Write it down and compare.

Comment: At some point, the OP will realize that Taylor is so much insanely easier than these binomial manipulations.

Comment: @rlgordonma Hopefully. I was lucky, I learned Taylor before I was asked to compute this kind of limits.

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks for the support, Babak.

Comment: @julien The dots hide some unspoken reasoning that is bordering on unjustified at the level of a homework problem.  Splitting it obviates the need for any dots and is certainly more convenient for something like $2\sqrt{1 - x} - \sqrt[3]{1+x^3} - \sqrt[4]{1-2x}$.

Comment: Thank you guys, I know what derivative and some to most of the shortcuts are(I took Cal in High school) but since we haven't covered it in class I can't use it, thank you for the answer though!  we solved it another longer way that I'll try to post

Comment: @ErickWong Then why don't you go ahead and write an answer with this example in addition if you think the method is really worth the generalization? These exercices are insane. And there is absolutely no good or interesting solution without Taylor.

Comment: @julien: Always, Welcome Julien.

Answer (score 2):

As $x \rightarrow 0$, you can ignore the $x^2$ pieces, as they go to zero faster than $x$.  the limit is then equivalent to

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-(1-2 x)^{1/4}}{x}$$

Now use the difference of two fourth powers:

$$y^4-z^4 = (y-z)(y+z)(y^2+z^2)$$

which means that

$$1-(1-2 x)^{1/4} = \frac{2 x}{(1+(1-2 x)^{1/4})(1+(1-2 x)^{1/2})}$$

The limit is then $2/((2)(2)) = 1/2$.

**EDIT**

Because a question was raised about the intuitive approach, I will make a little justification about my first statement.  Write

$$(1+x^2)^{1/3} - (1-2 x)^{1/4} =( 1-(1-2 x)^{1/4}) - (1-(1+x^2)^{1/3})$$

For the second term on the RHS, use $y^3-z^3 = (y-z)(y^2+yz+z^2)$ and get

$$1-(1+x^2)^{1/3} = \frac{-x^2}{1+(1+x^2)^{1/3} + (1+x^2)^{2/3}}$$

which, when divided by $x$, goes to zero in the limit.

Comment: How do you justify you can ignore the $x^2$ pieces without Taylor, or something equivalent?

Comment: It doesn't take Taylor to see that $x+x^2 \sim x$.

Comment: I am talking about $\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}$ that you replaced by $1$.

Comment: It is the same thing.  I could just as easily went ahead with $(1+x^2)^{1/3} - (1-2 x)^{1/4} =( 1-(1-2 x)^{1/4}) - (1-(1+x^2)^{1/3})$ and came to the same conclusion.  But I decided to go with the intuitive approach.

Comment: True. But that's quite a shortcut.

Comment: I made an edit to make this more clear.  But facility with these sort of limits makes that shortcut pretty plain.  It also makes one realize when one cannot use such a shortcut as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer!  we solved it another longer way that I'll try to post

Answer (score 2):

Although as comments above you are not familiar with the following fact; I am writing it here to keep it for the next.In fact @julien did the answer completely. The function $\alpha(x)$ can be said very small at $x\to a$ when $$\lim\alpha(x)\to 0$$ There are some facts about such this function. For example $\sqrt[n]{1+\alpha(x)}-1\sim\frac{\alpha(x)}{n}$. So $$\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-\sqrt[4]{1-2x}=(\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}-1)-(\sqrt[4]{1-2x}-1)~\sim~\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{-2x}{4}=\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x}{2}$$ when $x\to 0$ from both sides. I think the problem gets easy from here.

Comment: A nice fact to store for future use! +1

Comment: While it is a nice fact, it is very similar to using l'Hopital, or Taylor.